# semantic vocabulary to indicate count (people) and extension (across nations)

Tags: semantic-web, schema.org, rdfa

I need to often deal with membership numbers of an organization or group and the extension (number of countries involved) of that group and yet, in common vocabularies like schema.org or FOAF or the W3C organiztion ontology, I do not seem to be able to find a way of marking up a simple thing like '13,000 members' or 'covering 10 countries', or where I find these figures in a column in a table. Am I missing something very simple here?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you searched [Linked Open Vocabularies (LOV)](http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/) or looked at the [DBpedia Ontology](http://dbpedia.org/Ontology)?

You can suggest new properties to be added to schema.org to the [public-vocabs@w3.org mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/).

Finally you can also create your own vocabulary of properties if they don't exist anywhere else.

Comment: Yes I did check the two you mentioned, but was still bemused by the fact that there is nothing that quite (or so it seems to me) enables me to describe the numeric fields in a simple table indicating that 'this organization has x number of members and covers y number of countries. There is the W3C Data Cube vocab - but I wodnered if it was too complicated for this simple purpose!